# Firebase PWA - Offline CUD data sync

Tags: firebase, progressive-web-apps

I want to create a PWA using Firebase. I have found several tutorials showing how to use local storage to access read only data, but none showing how to draft offline CUD changes and resync them when online.
Any hints/tutorials along those lines would really help.
Thank you.
Joce M

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the **background sync** feature of Service Workers. Here are some links that you might find helpful:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync
https://ponyfoo.com/articles/backgroundsync